# OpenUI5 Data Binding / Expression Binding towards Parent

Tags: sapui5

In my OpenUI5 XML view, I have a `<List items="{path: 'instances'}">`. From the XML elements inside that list, how can I refer to a property of the parent? Is there an easy shortcut to render an item differently when it is an only child? I tried `visible="{= ${this.parent.instances}.length === 1}`, but this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript in the binding syntax does not work in UI5 beyond the [general binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/6c7c5c266b534e7ea9a28f861dc515f5.html) syntax & the [expression binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/5cff8d1c3fb84c5db7a00f2daca125af.html) syntax. You could however achieve this with a formatter function. You can access the parent within the formatter.

You can add the formatter in the XML code

```
visible="{
            path: 'Name',
            formatter: '.formatter.display'
        }"
```

And in the formatter code you can then check the parent

```
display : function(sName){
        var oList = this.getView().byId("list1");

        //You code below to check any of the parents properties
        //You code below to check any of the parents properties
        var oBinding = oList.getBinding("items"),
            iItems = oBinding.iLength;
        if(iItems.length === 1){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }  
    }
```